# get next Object from an recyclerView in detail activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView (using an adapter) containing some items. When I click on a particular listitem, it shows the details of that particular object. At the moment, only the specific dataobject is put to detail activity by using parcelable.

On the detail activity, I want to implement two buttons, that shows next and previous item.

How do I show the next item? Do I have to put the whole adapter with the List of all items to detail activity? How? I think it's no problem to show the data of the next/previous object if I get that object from the list, but at the moment I have no idea how to get that it at all...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you have to share your whole dataset between two Activities.

Comment: Whats the best way to share an array of objects between the activities? I'm also thiniking about memory... Maybe I can transfer an array of IDs and load nex object from database if next/previous is clicked...

Comment: Are the items stored in a database?

Comment: yes, they are stored in database

Comment: I think it will be enough to pass the currently selected item id. The data stored in the db is shared. So you can create a list of primary keys and keep an index variable to this array to track which one is selected.

Answer (score 0):

check if the current select is first or not.. if first then fetch current and next >> put both in intent and send to next. like

```
if(getAdapterPosition()>0) previousObject = mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition()-1);

firstObject = mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition());

SecondObject = mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition()+1);
```

put them in Bundle separately.

send to next.
get them in next activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if first object is shown in activity and next is clicked, I can show secons object. What if second object is shown and next is clicked?